# How to handle per object permission in Django nowadays?

Tags: django, django-guardian

I was about to use [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) until I came across the following in the official documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

> Permissions can be set not only per type of object, but also per specific object instance. By using the has_add_permission(), has_change_permission() and has_delete_permission() methods provided by the ModelAdmin class, it is possible to customize permissions for different object instances of the same type.

Does that mean django-guardian is no longer needed with newer versions of Django?

Please clarify.

Comment: Those methods aren't new. And note they only apply to the admin.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247890/2586761

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Indeed, while reading the docs, I got excited that Django would cater for "per object permissions checking" out of the box, [especially in the admin](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/RowLevelPermissions),  and that it would be a matter of time to understand how I could activate it.

However, [this does not seem to always be the case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).

Django [undoubtedly strives](https://github.com/djangoadvent/djangoadvent-articles/blob/master/1.2/06_object-permissions.rst) to provide the grounds (API) for such an implementation, but this implementation sometimes needs good coding skills and Django understanding.

It is the developer who will get these tools together by [creating the app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) that suits its needs. This could be either easy or ... not so easy!

This contradicting information forms the base for my web crawling which focuses on finding a solution to the "per-object permissions" issue, somehow ... effectively for my project's needs or scale and of course my own coding skills and Django understanding up to now.

[Django-guardian](https://pypi.org/project/django-guardian/) seems to be the most robust, full-fledged, full-blown application for this purpose, and it also has a [3 years old open issue](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/506) regarding its admin integration.

There are also other [more lightweight django applications](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/) that address specific needs which are production-stable, as well.

While trying to make ends meet in this somehow tricky quest, I am leaning towards using [django-rules](https://pypi.org/project/rules/) for its simple and focused on my needs functioning.

Comment: I wanted to implement object level permission with Django Admin site. I went with [Django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian), sadly it **did not work** even with the [example that is shipped with the package](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/tree/devel/example_project). [The issue is not addressed](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/506) for over 3 years. I wouldn't recommend Django Guardian.

Comment: @vignz.pie Django Guardian as I mentioned in the post, is a huge project with a steep learning curve. I would not go with it either, instead as I also mention in the post, I am leaning towards using [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules). Thank you for mentioning this particular issue of Django-guardian, for django-admin, however. I have updated my post.