# Object-level permissions in Django

Tags: django

I have a `ListView` as follows, enabling me to loop over two models (`Market` and `ScenarioMarket`) in a template:

```
class MarketListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'market_list'
    template_name = 'market_list.html'
    queryset = Market.objects.all()
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MarketListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['scenariomarkets'] = ScenarioMarket.objects.all()
        context['markets'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

The two market models are as follows:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.50)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    shares_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class ScenarioMarket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    most_likely = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Not defined")
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenario_market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

And my user model is as follows:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    points = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20, 
        decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal('1000.00'),
        verbose_name='User points'
    )

    bets_placed = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name='Bets placed'
    )

    net_gain = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20, 
        decimal_places=2,
        default=Decimal('0.00'),
        verbose_name='Net gain'
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-net_gain']
```

What I want happen is that **different users see different sets of markets**. For example, I want users from company X to only see markets pertaining to X, and same for company Y, Z, and so forth.

Four possibilities so far, and their problems:

1. I could **hardcode** this: If each user has a `company` feature (in addition to `username`, etc.), I could add a `company` feature to each market as well, and then use `if` tags in the template to ensure that the right users see the right markets. **Problem**: Ideally I'd want to do this through the Admin app: whenever a new market is created there, it would be specified what company can see it.
2. I could try to use **Django's default permissions**, which of course would be integrated with Admin. **Problem**: Setting a view permission (e.g., [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)) would concern the entire model, not particular instances of it.
3. From googling around, it seems that something like [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/assign.html) might be what I ultimately have to go with. **Problem**: As I'm using a `CustomUser` model, it seems I might run into problems there (see [here](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0/userguide/custom-user-model.html)).
4. **I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247890/5674156) here on SO**, which would enable me to do this without relying on django-guardian. **Problem**: I'm not clear on how to integrate that into the Admin app, in the manner that django-guardian seems able to.

If anyone has any advice, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about customize the `queryset` by using a filter instead of `.all()` ?

Comment: @PRMoureu thanks for the comment. Sure, I could add a company feature to the markets (as per option 1 above) and then filter the queryset by company. But would that filter be sensitive to the company affiliation of the current user (so users from company X only see markets for company X, and so forth)?

Comment: If you have a relation between User <> Company and Market <> Company , you can filter the related markets:  `self.request.user` gives the current user, from there you can select the company for a filter. Can you add the models if you need more details ?

Comment: @PRMoureu this sounds promising! I've added the models to the original post.

Comment: Ok, silly question but i'm not sure how you want to implement the relationships with Markets, one market can have many Companies ? And one user is tied to only one company right ?

Comment: @PRMoureu not silly at all! Yes, that's right: one user is tied to only one company, and each market can in principle be tied to several companies (although in reality will typically only be associated with one company).

Comment: But where are those relationships defined? You don't seem to have any fields that define a relationship between Market, User and Company.

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct. PRMoureu suggested that defining such relationships and then filtering the queryset was better than looking at object-level permissions, which raised the question of how best to define those relationships - that’s where we’re at right now and I haven’t had a chance to start on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some relationships between the models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey('Market', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

then in your view you can simply filter the queryset as appropriate:

```
class MarketListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'market_list'
    template_name = 'market_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Market.objects.filter(company__user=self.request.user)
```

Note, you don't need the `context['markets'] = self.queryset` line in your get_context_data; the queryset is already available as `market_list`, since that's what you set the `context_object_name` to.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, this should work! One question: am I right in thinking that, since there are existing records in the database, doing this will require removing/altering existing migration files, given that `ForeignKey` is non-NULLable by default? Or can I get around that by setting `null=True`? Am asking because a version of this is already deployed on Heroku so want to minimise disruption to existing records.

Comment: Yes, null=True will allow you to migrate