# How to add more features to user permission in django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-permissions, django-custom-user

I am new to django. I want to edit default user auth_permissions. More precisely I want to add an integer field in addition to "label", "code" features to distinct permission types (like strong, moderate and etc.). So far I could not find anything like this. I tried to make custom permissions, but could not add them to the permission database. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per Object permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227521/django-per-object-permission-for-your-own-user-model)

When i first got into django i also tried relying on the permissions framework within django, I also found the permissions were too broad and inefficient, which lead me to researching *django-guardian*, I tried to submit an edit to the Django project itself to make more object-base permissions with no success, they said as per object permissions were too personalised for the framework.

The thing is, after getting to work in the industry i realised how people do these permissions in the industry (which honestly was something that bugged me), they mainly create custom login middlewares to keep track of authentication types and add the checks on the view itself. So basically you will have to check in the view who the user is and if you want to give them permission to whatever.

When in MIT they kept asking me to make some weird permissions and I created a table called ExtraordinaryPermissions, this had a ForeignKey to the user and could be used to check within the views what objects the user had access to

It is troublesome, but as-per-object permissions are handed this way in the industry

good luck

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess it is the answer I needed.

Comment: @AytajBadirova then make sure to like and flag it as final answer :P