# Django: multiple admin page consuming same model but different auth mode

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a Django site which is capable of supporting multiple organizations. Each organizations will have its own staff and admin, and each staff can only login to the admin page of their organization, and CRUD data input from staff of the same organization as them.

So far, I don't have any problem create multiple admin pages extending AdminSite. But I don't know how I can assign admin/staff account to their own organization so that they can only access their organization's Admin Page and the organization's data accordingly (a staff account now can enter any AdminPage).

I'm also not sure what is the best way to filter data for each Admin Page. 
What I have in mind for now is adding one more 'group' column for my Data Model, and filter the query in each admin page based on the 'group' of the person querying.

Any help and insight on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override `AdminSite.has_permission` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.has_permission)), if you are extending the base `AdminSite` class.

As for the second part of your question, it sounds like you are looking for something like object-level permissions.[django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) might be a good extension to look at. Also, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815900/1138710) has a some interesting thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It was a great help. 
In the end I modify the permission method in the DataModelAdmin to filter my queries.

Comment: If it was helpful, please accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django Tenant, it's the man for this problem